# Not being able to call a particular column after grouping data week-wise in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, resampling, quantitative-finance

I tried to convert daily data to weekly data in Pandas, but when I want to perform calculations with a particular column from the grouped data frame, I cannot do so.

This is my code:

```
df_w['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_w['Date'])
df_w.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df_w.sort_index(inplace=True)




def take_first(array_like):
    return array_like[0]

def take_last(array_like):
    return array_like[-1]

output_w = df_w.resample('W',                                 # Weekly resample
                how={'Date2': take_first,
                    'Open': take_first, 
                     'High': 'max',
                     'Low': 'min',
                     'Close': take_last,
                     'Volume': 'sum'}, 
                loffset=pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6))  # to put the labels to Monday


df_w = output_w[['Date2','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]

df_w[ 'EMA_40' ] = df_w['Close'].ewm( span = 40, adjust=False ).mean()
```

This is the error message:

```
df_w[ 'EMA_40' ] = df_w['Close'].ewm( span = 40, adjust=False ).mean()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 2178, in mean
return self._apply('ewma', **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 2149, in _apply
values = self._prep_values(b.values)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 219, in _prep_values
dtype=values.dtype))
NotImplementedError: ops for EWM for this dtype datetime64[ns] are not implemented
```

I realized that I'm making a mistake while grouping the data, since, upon printing the new 'Close', instead of a column being printed, the entire data frame of Open, High, Low, and Close is being printed.

While printing df_w and df_w[ 'Close' ], this is the output:

```
          index                  close   ...      Open      Low     High
Date                                           ...                            
2014-07-28   1008 2014-08-01   41.41   ...     41.12  41.0200  41.7300
2014-08-04   1003 2014-08-08   41.44   ...     40.79  40.7800  41.4600
2014-08-11    998 2014-08-15   41.97   ...     41.84  41.7400  42.2200
2014-08-18    993 2014-08-22   42.45   ...     42.75  42.2100  42.7500
```

Is there a way to rectify this?

I could source my data from Quandl, and it works then, but Quandl doesn't provide data beyond 27th March, 2018.

EDIT: This is the output before resampling:

```
print ( df_w[ 'Close' ])
print ( df_w[ 'High' ])

2018-08-01 00:00:00    52.450
2018-08-03 13:35:00    52.610
Name: Close, Length: 1009, dtype: float64

018-08-01 00:00:00    52.6000
2018-08-03 13:35:00    52.8700
Name: High, Length: 1009, dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you add the code for 'upon printing the new 'close'?

Comment: The error message says that `df_w['Close']` is of type `datetime64` and it does not support operation `.ewm`. What is `ewm` and why do you think you can apply it to a datetime column?

Comment: ewm is exponential moving average. df_w[ 'Close' ] is not supposed to be a datetime object. Upon grouping the data week-wise, it is being converted to a datetime object; that is the issue.

Comment: Please include a small sample of your data.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: With random data, I cannot reproduce your error: [pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/cf4b9c2c-ac8d-46f4-aec7-5d46493aa106/?i=true). Click Run in demo.

Comment: Thanks. There must be something wrong in the way I am reading the csv file. Any suggestions on how I could approach this?

Comment: Please print *df_w* and its `dtypes` before `resample`.

Comment: Please have a look now.